# This keyword in some case not clear

Tags: c#

when I doing a coding I come across a function like this =>

```
public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute): this(execute, null)
```

I really dont know about the "this" key word usage here

Comment: `this` in that context usually means call another constructor of *this* class with these arguments. It is a way of reducing code duplication

Answer (score 5):

It's constructor chaining.  `this(execute, null)` calls another constructor defined in that class which takes an `Action<object>` and some other value.  For example:

```
class Whatever
{
    public Whatever() : this("string arg") {}  // calls Whatever(string)

    public Whatever(string something) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular use of `this` keyword lets you call one  constructor from the other, presumably to supply a default argument. You can "fold" both constructors into one by applying default parameter values:

```
public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, string name = null) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is referring to an overloaded version of the current constructor.
Basically the two constructors are chained together which can be good for avoiding duplicate code in constructors